# How do I generate a filter string for JSON

Tags: json, swift

Are there any conventions to generate a filter text for the objects I use in Swift ?

```
class Account {
  var active : Bool!
  ...
}
```

Example : I've Account class in Swift and Account model in loopback, I want to get the Accounts with field "active = true"
the filter that I need to generate is = `{"where" : {"active" : true}}`

I type these kinds of queries by hand in need. I'm sure there's a way that someone thought about it, I just need the keyword.

PS: I extend my classes from Realm and ObjectMapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated answer**

If I understand your comment under my original answer, you need to *generate* a JSON *String* in the form of `{"where" : {"active" : true}}` where `true` is actually the bool value of your `Account` instance. This JSON String will then be used as a query/filter for MongoDB.

For this, I suggest you add a computed property to the `Account` class. This property will use `NSJSONSerialization` to create the JSON *data* from the bool, and use `String()` to create a JSON *String* from this data.

Example:

```
class Account {
    var active : Bool!

    var boolQuery: String? {
        let dict = ["where": ["active": active]]
        if let json = try? NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options: []),
                query = String(data: json, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
            return query
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let acc = Account()
acc.active = true
if let query = acc.boolQuery {
    print(query)
}
```

Prints:

> {"where":{"active":true}}

```
let acc = Account()
acc.active = false
if let query = acc.boolQuery {
    print(query)
}
```

Prints:

> {"where":{"active":false}}

I'm not sure if I got the "who does what" in your setup (which class is reponsible for what), but it seems to me that it's the kind of code you needed.

It can also be a free function of course:

```
func boolQuery(account: Account) -> String? {
    let dict = ["where": ["active": account.active]]
    if let json = try? NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options: []),
        query = String(data: json, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        return query
    }
    return nil
}
```

Etc.

---

**Previous answer**

It's a bit unclear from your question, and I'm not sure what you mean with *"I type these kinds of queries by hand in need"*... but I suppose that, anyway, you have an array of `Account` instances.

Then it's very easy to filter this array and get only the instances where `active` is `true`:

```
let result = arrayOfAccounts.filter { $0.active }
```

Here `result` is an array containing only the accounts where `active` is true.

Comment: The problem is I don't own these instances in swift, they live in mongoDB. I fetch them using these queries. Thanks